# printing output using object in python

Tags: python, class, object

```
class hive:
   def abc(str):
      name = str
      return name + ' welcome'

def main():
  obj = hive()
  print('enter name')
  string = input()
  print(obj.abc(string))

if __name__ == "__main__": main()
```

> I want to print name with welcome string concatenated with it,but I can't be able to do so and I am getting  the error below :

```
C:\Users\SHUBHAM TANDAN\Desktop\python>class.py 
enter name
shubham
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\SHUBHAM TANDAN\Desktop\python\class.py", line 12, in <module>
if __name__ == "__main__": main()
File "C:\Users\SHUBHAM TANDAN\Desktop\python\class.py", line 10, in main
print(obj.abc(string))
TypeError: abc() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

> Can anyone please help me find the error in the above code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When making classes in python, all nested functions must have the 'self' argument.

```
class hive:
   def abc(self, str):
      name = str
      return name + ' welcome'
```

Comment: obj.abc(string) is analogous to hive.abc(obj, string).